# Using netbook motherboard in PC build, need way to press power button from 7-8 inches away

Tags: laptop, power-supply, netbook, emulation

I'm using the case out of an early Sega Genesis/Megadrive to build a low power emulation/media PC. The following picture is an aerial view. The power button is on the top right, but underneath the motherboard.

**I need a way to press that button from a different location that doesn't involve soldering**. I'm not using Sega's power switch, but I am re-using the location. Right now the area where the power slider is completely empty.

[image]

[image]

Netbook power button.
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? The simplest solution would be remove the current power switch and replace it.  Yes;  This would require soldering skills.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this remotely? I wanted to avoid modifying the board.